# Sql Delete Query Based on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-delete

Suppose I have two table. One is Car_Window and another is Product. Now I want to write a delete statement that should delete all data from Product

> Where the Car_Window.Id = Product.Makeid and Car_Window.Year = Product.Year and Car_Window.Model != product.Model

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to explain this better, delete ALL data from Product is just:
DELETE FROM Product

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    product a
        INNER JOIN car_window b
            ON a.makeID = b.ID AND
                a.Year = b.year
WHERE   b.Model != a.Model
```